# How to call boost register_type function for dynamic type member

Tags: c++, templates, serialization, boost, virtual-functions

There is class `A` which have pointer `p` to some base class. I need to make class `A` and its derived classes serializable using boost serialization. To make `p`-member serializable there is need to call `register_type<TYPE_OF_P>()`. How can I make virtual template function with archive parameter which calls `register_type` with own type name of `p`?

```
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>

struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() {}

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        // ar & baseMember1
        // ar & baseMember2
        // ...
    }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    virtual ~Derived() {}

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(*this);
        // ar & derivedMember1
        // ar & derivedMember2
        // ...
    }
};

class A
{
public:
    A() { p = 0; }
    virtual ~A() = 0 { delete p; }

    template<class Archive> // Must be like a virtual function member
    /*virtual*/ void registerType(Archive &ar)
    {
    }

protected:
    Base *p; // Initialize in a constructor
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() { p = new Derived; }

    //template<class Archive>
    //virtual(!) void registerType(Archive &ar)
    //{
    //    ar.register_type<Derived>();
    //}
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    A *a = &b;

    std::string s;
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ss);

    oa << a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the syntax to qualify a member template?

```
class A
{
public:
    A() { p = 0; }
    virtual ~A() = 0 { delete p; }
    A(A const&) = delete;            // RULE OF THREE!
    A& operator==(A const&) = delete;// RULE OF THREE!

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned)
    {
         ar.template register_type<Derived1>();
         ar.template register_type<Derived2>();
         ar.template register_type<Derived3>();
    }

protected:
    Base *p; // Initialize in a constructor
};
```

Obviously, member templates cannot be virtual. Also, this would appear to be a misguided goal.

Consider when you are deserializing from a freshly instantiated archive. You **need** to tell the archive about all the dynamic types it might be encountering, before you can start deserializing them. Obviously, you cannot leave the work to the derived types themselves because that would just be too late.

The runtime dynamism is in the lookup by `typeid`, not in the type itself.

#### EXPORT classes

There's **one** other mechanism though: you can use the EXPORT macros to make registration "automatic". The mechanism here is that of singletons, and the order in which you include headers and "invoke" those EXPORT macros is of the utmost importance. Notably, you need to include all the archive headers of archive types that you *may* wish to be using at runtime *before* the class export macros.

- Doc: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#export